# Render only if prop satisfies condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and this might be a very silly question but please bear with me.
I am trying to render dynamic object through props in react native. But the object is not loaded to the component by the time it renders. I wrote an if condition to be satisfied for the object to be loaded but I am getting

```
Error: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

I could have added an else statement, but the point is to wait till the props status is 'available'. any explanation is deeply appreciated.

```
render() {
    if (this.props.object?.status === 'available') {
        console.info('Log value= ', this.props);

        const path = "String" + this.props.object;
        console.info('abc =', path);

        return (
            <View
                document={path}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely the answer you're looking for is in the error message `Or, to render nothing, return null`

Answer (score 3):

You always need to return *something* in a `render()` function.

Add a `return null` at the top with an inverted `if`.

```
  render() {
    if (this.props.object?.status !== 'available') return null;

    console.info('Log value= ',this.props);
      
    const path = "String"+this.props.object;
    console.info('abc =',path);
    
    return (
      <View
        document={path}   
        />
    );
  }
```